# How to determine the eigenvector in the case of $\lambda=\infty$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ we want to determine the eigenpairs of the general eigenvalue problem.

From the following properties we have:

$(\lambda,x) $ eigenpair of $(A,B) \iff (A-\lambda B)x=0$ , $x\ne 0$.

Then we have $P(\lambda)=-\lambda \Rightarrow \sigma(A,B)=\{ 0,\infty\}$

My question is how to determine the eigenvector in the case of $\lambda=\infty$ ?

Comment: $(\lambda,x)$ is eigenpair of $(A,B)$ iff $(\frac1\lambda,x)$ is eigenpair of $(B,A)$

Comment: I would guess that, provided that $\sigma(A,B)$ stands, loosely speaking, for the "solutons in $\Bbb P^1\Bbb C$" to the inequation $\dim\ker (A-\lambda B)>0$, then $\infty\in\sigma(A,B)$ means that $\dim\ker(0A-B)>0$, i.e. that $B$ is singular. If you want, you can see this as $[\alpha:\beta]\in\Bbb P^1\Bbb C$ being in $\sigma(A,B)$ if and only if $\dim\ker(\alpha A-\beta B)>0$.

Comment: In simple terms eigenvalues of these matrices are $1,0$ with eigenvectors as $(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T$.

Comment: Emm I see .. Thank you :)